# ValueError: math domain error python

Tags: python

Что не так в коде

```
import math


e = 0.00002

def fun(x):
    return math.log(6.0976*x, e)-6.872*x+1

x1 = float(input("Введите приближенное значение Х="))
a = float(input("a="))
b = float(input("b="))
a = abs((fun(a + 0.0001) - fun(a)) / 0.0001)
b = abs((fun(b + 0.0001) - fun(b)) / 0.0001)
q = max(a, b)
q = (1 - q) / q
iters = 0
x0 = x1
x1 = fun(x0)
while abs(x1 - x0) <= abs(q * e):
    iters += 1
    x0 = x1
    x1 = fun(x0)

print('Вычисленное значение корня:', x1)
print('Число итераций:', iters)
```

Что вылазит ошибка

```
return math.log(6.0976*x, e)-6.872*x+1
ValueError: math domain error
```

Comment: натуральный логарифм от отрицательного числа не существует - это надо учесть в логике программы

Comment: видимо, x полчуился отрицательным, логарифм определен только для положительных чисел